# Conjugate Prior for Multivariate Normal Variances and Correlations

Tags: bayesian, prior, multivariate-normal-distribution, conjugate-prior

Is there a way to separately specify conjugate priors for the variance and correlations of a multivariate normal? The inverse Wishart is conjugate if you want to specify the covariance, but covariance matrices aren't very intuitive. Is it possible to instead specify a prior over the correlations, and separately a prior over the marginal variance for each parameter, while still keeping conjugacy?